# How to trigger ng-change from jquery?

Tags: angularjs

I have a select tag as follows:

```
<select ng-change="doSomething()" ng-model="myModel"> </select>
```

and I'm using a jQueryUI control for it (combobox), the event "change" triggered from jQuery doesn't trigger doSomething().

Do you know how to trigger ng-change from outside angular?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The question is not how to run some code, but rather how to trigger the change event. I found an angular-friendly way to do this. I have a jQuery UI slider that changes the value of another input which has the ng-change on it. The secret is that once you turn it into an angular.element you now have access to a method called triggerHandler. From what I've seen, using this would not be considered bad practice:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('test')).triggerHandler('change');
```

tymeJV's answer did `angular.element("#test")` directly without using jQuery, but I got a console error and broken functionality that way. This version works without any dependencies.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed when a jQuery `.trigger('change')` didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. THis allows you to trigger the ng-change method on the element pragmatically through javascript. Very useful when you have a custom directive that handles your input and you need to trigger the change function when the input vale changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, helped me as well!

Answer (score 6):

Ugh - this is terrible practice - but you can use `angular.element` and get the `scope` from an element that resides within the target controller.

Example:

```
<div ng-controller="myApp">
    <span id="test"></span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var scope = angular.element("#test").scope();
scope.doSomething();
```

Your `scope` variable now has access to all the methods defined on the `myApp` controller.

Comment: If this is terrible practice, then what to do with input elements that are populated with a default value on the server?

Comment: @BauceLawyerson -- Don't populate the input `value` attribute - instead parse the server value via Angular and assign it to the correct `ngModel` variable.

Comment: This works only in debug mode. angular.element("#id").scope() is not available when in release mode. see the section about "Retrieving Scopes from the DOM". [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)