# Run ng-change functions on load for pre-checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I have an function within ng-change that executes every time a checkbox is checked (manually).

Now I want to have the checkboxes pre-checked on load and the function within ng-change to execute as well (on load).

What are some of the approaches I can take to achieve this?

Comment: `ng-init`? Did you try anything?

Comment: ng-init was the first directive I tried using to initialize the function; however, the expected results did not get returned. Was wondering if there's any other approach than ng-init.

Comment: Are you not using a controller or directive? I don't understand why the function you call in the ng-change can't be called directly from the JS on the controller init/directive link. `ng-change="update()"` -> `scope.update(); // on controller`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that, your model will automatically do it, say

$scope.customer = customer;

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='customer.active' /> Is Active
```

It will take care automatically

Comment: ... except for OP might actually need the method in ngChange to be invoked, which your solution does not cover.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a function which will be triggered on load and during onChange event as well, you can use a directive **ng-init**

Create onLoad and onChange functions connected to your scope:

```
$scope.onLoad = function(params) {
  // do some init functionality and call onChange functionality
  onChange();
}

$scope.onChange = function(value) {
  // do function when a combobox is chaned
}
```

In HTML template you have to bind those methods

```
<div ng-init="onLoad()">
  <input type='checkbox' ng-model='someModel' ng-change="('1')"/> Is one
  <input type='checkbox' ng-model='someModel' ng-change="('2')"/> Is two
  <input type='checkbox' ng-model='someModel' ng-change="('3')"/> Is three
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-change` will not execute unless the input has been changed by a user as stated on the angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange). The thing is that you can manually trigger the ng-change but its generally not suggested and it is considered a [dirty way and terrible practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330467/how-to-trigger-ng-change-from-jquery). It will be more apropriate to add a watcher and detect any changes made to the model.

```
$scope.$watch("myModel", function(newValue, oldValue){
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how to manually trigger the ng-change?